# storing and re-using decltype value?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, decltype

if I have a template:

```
template <class T>
struct Item
{
  T _value;
};
```

I can then do:

```
// ...
Item<int> x = { 42 }; // declared as an int

// ...
decltype(x._value) y = 20; // 'y' is also an int
```

But is it possible to store the `decltype` to a variable so it can be used later?

Why?
I want to store the values of items as pointer.

Something like `std::vector<Item*>` but as they are templates I have to store them as pointers to `void`:

```
std::vector<void*> is;
is.push_back(new Item<int>());
is.push_back(new Item<double>());
is.push_back(new Item<float>());
```

And this is all fine, but when it comes time to delete the pointer I need to re-cast my `void*` back to the proper type (so the destructors are called):

```
delete (Item<int>*)is[0];
```

And if I know the type, I could do:

```
delete (Item<decltype(whatever)>*)is[0];
```

Hence the reason I would need to store the `decltype`.

I hope this makes sense.

Comment: You should check out Boost.variant and Boost.any (or their C++17 counterparts [`std::variant`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) and [`std::any`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any)). They are probably better implementations of what you need.

Comment: Type erasure is the keyword, in C it is done with `void*`, in C++ is done with `std::any` and the visitor pattern. The smart pointer solutions in fact use a some kind of type erasure internally.

Comment: @alfC Note that type erasure is performed at compile time, while the basic idea behind the visitor pattern is the double dispatching, that is a runtime machinery.

Comment: Have you considered using a common base class for `Item<T>` which has a virtual destructor?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`decltype` is a language feature that allows you to retrieve a type at compile-time. It seems that you want to "store" that type so that you can correctly `delete` objects allocated on the dynamic storage at run-time. Assuming that's the case, `decltype` is not going to help here.

You have various options:

1. Use some form of type-erasing facility like `Boost.Variant` or `Boost.Any`, as suggested by *Baum mit Augen* in the comments.
2. Make your objects part of a polymorphic hierarchy and use smart pointers:

   ```
   struct ItemBase 
   {
       virtual ~ItemBase() { }
   };

   template <class T>
   struct Item : ItemBase
   {
       T _value;
   };

   int main() 
   {
       std::vector<std::unique_ptr<ItemBase>> items;
       items.emplace_back(std::make_unique<Item<int>>());
       items.emplace_back(std::make_unique<Item<float>>());                     
       items.emplace_back(std::make_unique<Item<double>>());
   }
   ```

Comment: Language lawyers will come saying that there is no _heap_ anywhere to which to allocate. _Dynamic storage_ is more appropriated maybe.

Comment: Number 2 is by far the simplest and most performant. There might even be shared functionality that ends up ItemBase!

Comment: @rubenvb Number 2 also requires the OP to modify his hierarchy and it could be not possible (as an example if `Item` is part of another library).

Comment: @skypjack What do you mean there is no heap?

Comment: @0x499602D2 I mean that there is nothing named _heap_ in the standard.

Comment: Thanks, this does exactly what I need. I didn't think unique_ptrs could be used that way...

Answer (score 5):

If the problem is only to delete them, you can use `unique_ptr` with a custom deleter instead of naked pointers.
You don't need to modify your hierarchy to do this.
As an example:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<void, void(*)(void*)>> is;
is.push_back(std::unique_ptr<void, void(*)(void*)>{new Item<int>(), [](void *ptr) { delete static_cast<Item<int>*>(ptr); }});
```

Even better if using `emplace_back` instead of `push_back`:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<void, void(*)(void*)>> is;
is.emplace_back(new Item<int>(), [](void *ptr) { delete static_cast<Item<int>*>(ptr); });
```

It follows a minimal, working example based on the OP's code:

```
#include<vector>
#include<memory>

template<typename>
struct Item {};

int main() {
    using Deleter = void(*)(void*);
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<void, Deleter>> is;
    is.emplace_back(new Item<int>(), [](void *ptr) { delete static_cast<Item<int>*>(ptr); }); 
    is.emplace_back(new Item<double>(), [](void *ptr) { delete static_cast<Item<double>*>(ptr); }); 
    is.emplace_back(new Item<float>(), [](void *ptr) { delete static_cast<Item<float>*>(ptr); }); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, nice and clean way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

You may store the *deleter*

so with `std::shared_ptr`, it becomes:

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<void>> items;

// The simplest
items.push_back(std::make_shared<Item<int>>(/*args...*/));

// Explicitly specify the (default) deleter
items.push_back(std::shared_ptr<void>{new Item<double>(/*args...*/),
                                      std::default_delete<Item<double>>{}});

// Explicitly specify the (default) allocator
items.push_back(
    std::allocate_shared<Item<float>>(std::allocator<Item<float>>{} /*, args...*/);
```